# sharepoint online list form opens in new tab, how do I change that?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a sharepoint online site with a list in it. Whenever I try to add an item to the list it opens a new window for the form. How do I change it so the form opens on the right side of the same window?

Comment: Are you using modern experience and list? Are you trying to open the new item from list view or any site page? is there any customization on list view/page

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to list settings->Advanced settings->Choose "No" under "Launch forms in a dialog", then when you click new item, it will open it in a tab instead of a windows dialog.

[image]